# missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

In my code I'm getting:

> missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call swift

I'm a beginner to Swift and I've already tried everything including researching this question, but have found no answer. Thanks.

The code I'm getting this error is:

`let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: ChecklistViewController().view.frame.width / 2 + 117, y: ChecklistViewController().view.frame.size.height - 70), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))`

Comment: You should edit the question to share the line of code that is generating this error.

Comment: Alright, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The error is suggesting that the compiler is having trouble figuring out which `init` method should be invoked, so it's assuming you meant to call `init(coder:)`.

But let's set that aside for a second. First, let's simplify your statement to eliminate some "noise". Rather than using `CGRect(origin:, size:)`, you might use `CGRect(x:, y:, width:, height:)`. That would yield (separating it on separate lines to make it a little easier to read):

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(
    x: ChecklistViewController().view.frame.width / 2 + 117,
    y: ChecklistViewController().view.frame.size.height - 70,
    width: 50,
    height: 50)
)
```

Second, the problem here is that that `ChecklistViewController()` syntax isn't actually referencing your existing `ChecklistViewController`. Every time it sees `ChecklistViewController()` it's creating a new instance of that view controller (so you probably have three instances, the original one and the two you accidentally created here). That's certainly not what you intended. If you were doing this in, one of the instance methods of the view controller itself, you'd just reference `self`, e.g.:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(
    x: self.view.frame.width / 2 + 117,
    y: self.view.frame.size.height - 70,
    width: 50,
    height: 50)
)
```

A more subtle problem is that this code will only work if the `frame` of the `view` has been set. But if you have this code in `viewDidLoad`, the `frame` hasn't been set yet. If you did this in `viewDidAppear`, though, you could get away with this code. Generally, you'd use auto layout, to avoid this, e.g. something like:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
// do additional configuration of the button here

view.addSubview(button)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    button.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor, constant: 117),
    button.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor, constant: -70),
    button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50),
    button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50)
])
```

Because we did this with auto layout, it means you can do this in `viewDidLoad`, if you want. Also, it means that if you rotate the device, the constraints will recalculate the `frame` automatically for you.

Having said all of this, the "missing argument for parameter 'coder'" might be a result of some other problem in the code. But, if you fix the declaration of the button, you might be able to better diagnose any other issue that might be in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I used "self" in the code instead of ChecklistViewController(), I got a different error. This error said: Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ChecklistViewController' has no member of 'view'

Comment: You'd only use `self` if you were doing this from an instance method of the view controller. It doesn't sound like that's where you're doing this, but without more context we can't help. I.e., where do you have the code from your question? But bottom line, don't use `CheckViewController()` syntax, but rather get a reference to the existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using ChecklistViewController to generate your positions. 
Try this code

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame) + 117) , y: (CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) - 70) , size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))
```

Comment: When I tried that I got an error saying: Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ChecklistViewController' has no member 'view'

Comment: Are you making this in a viewController? And it need to be located within a class.